# Deploying huggingface zero-shot classification in Sagemaker using template returns error, missing positional argument 'candidate_labels'

Tags: python, model, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I'm using the generated code from huggingface, Task: `Zero-Shot Classification`, Configuration: `AWS` and running it in Sagemaker's jupyterlab

```py
from sagemaker.huggingface import HuggingFaceModel
import sagemaker

role = sagemaker.get_execution_role()
# Hub Model configuration. https://huggingface.co/models
hub = {
    'HF_MODEL_ID':'facebook/bart-large-mnli',
    'HF_TASK':'zero-shot-classification'
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
    transformers_version='4.6.1',
    pytorch_version='1.7.1',
    py_version='py36',
    env=hub,
    role=role, 
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
    initial_instance_count=1, # number of instances
    instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge' # ec2 instance type
)

predictor.predict({
    'inputs': "Hi, I recently bought a device from your company but it is not working as advertised and I would like to get reimbursed!"
})
```

The following error returned:

> ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the
> InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from primary
> with message "{   "code": 400,   "type": "InternalServerException",
> "message": "**call**() missing 1 required positional argument:
> \u0027candidate_labels\u0027" } ". See ...
> in account **** for more information.

I tried running them differently such as this,

```
predictor.predict({
    'inputs': "Hi, I recently bought a device from your company but it is not working as advertised and I would like to get reimbursed!",
    'candidate_labels': ['science', 'life']
})
```

but still don't work. How should I run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema of request body for a zero-shot classification model is defined in this [link](https://github.com/huggingface/notebooks/blob/772ddf7140bccc443da265c90c95eda99e69c564/sagemaker/10_deploy_model_from_s3/deploy_transformer_model_from_s3.ipynb).

```
{
    "inputs": "Hi, I recently bought a device from your company but it is not working as advertised and I would like to get reimbursed!",
    "parameters": {
        "candidate_labels": [
            "refund",
            "legal",
            "faq"
        ]
    }
}
```